# C# Google Парсинг

Tags: c#, веб-скрейпинг

Ребят я студент есть задача приложения для того что бы сделать запрос в гугл, и подсчитать количество слов на странице и вывести результат, так то все понятно но не как не могу с гуглом разобраться, соответственно запрос не через Web Api делаю.

```
    string GetPageText(string searchText)
    {
        string googleUrl = $"https://www.google.com.ua/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=792&bih=975&q= + {searchText} + &gs_l=img&gws_rd=cr";
        string data = string.Empty;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(googleUrl);
        request.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (dataStream != null)
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                {
                    data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        string crearText = string.Empty;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            crearText = ClearText(data);
        }

        return crearText;
    }
```

Comment: 1. Ошибка в формате интерполяции строк (+ {searchText} +), уберите плюсы. 2. «не могу с гуглом разобраться» — можно подробнее, что это значит?

Comment: 1 понял, а по поводу гугла, делаю запрос и не получаю той странички какой надо, не могу получить страничку с выдачей.